# XSLT: Zip Code splitting

Tags: transform, xslt-2.0

I have written an XSLT template that strips the last four digits in a 10 digit zip code. Format of an example zip code is 90201-3611. Here is the function:

```
<xsl:template name="ZipCode4Digits">
  <xsl:param name="zipCode"/>
  <xsl:param name="target"/>
   <xsl:if test="contains($zipCode,$target) and string-length(substring-        after($outputString,$target)) >1">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($zipCode,$target)"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately there are several zip code in the document output document and they all have different element names. For example in one place it is called `<shipping_zip>` and in another `<personZip>` and so on.  How can best generate these elements for the value obtained from the template?

Please help!

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is, if you want to generate different elements then you could for instance give the template an additional parameter `<xsl:param name="element-name"/>` and then create e.g. `<xsl:element name="{$element-name}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($zipCode,$target)"/></xsl:element>`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.